# regex on tnsnames.ora

Tags: regex, oracle, bash

my tnsnames.ora file has 2 formats :
db_cl =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = a55)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = cl)
    )
  )

dbcd =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = a66 )(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = cd)
    )
  )

myx5=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = v55)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = x5)
    )
  )

i want to get the hostname of a specific service_name or sid. in some cases it is sid and in some cases it is service_name. what should i search with grep in order to get the hostname? In this example i want to get the string "host_name".

****UPDATE****
I ALSO NEED THE db_name2, if someone can help

Comment: i want to find the hostname of a specific sid/service_Name

Answer (score 1):

@drf: try:

```
 awk '/HOST/{sub(/).*/,"",$(NF-2));print $(NF-2)}'   Input_file
```

Simply looking for string HOST for each line then substituting the ).* from the 2nd last filed of the line where awk matches the string HOST in it, it should give you host_name then.

EDIT: For looking for a specific SID or service name try:

```
awk '/HOST/{sub(/).*/,"",$(NF-2));HOST=$(NF-2);next} /SID/{print HOST}'
```

Change SID with sid or service name which you want to search and it should work then.

EDIT2:

```
awk '/db_name/{sub(/=/,"",$1);DB=$1}/HOST/{sub(/).*/,"",$(NF-2));HOST=$(NF-2);next} /chumma/{print DB ORS HOST}'
```

EDIT3:

```
awk '{gsub(/\)|\(/,"");;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="HOST"){host=$(i+1)};if($NF=="cd"){val="DB_NAME= "$1", HOST_NAME= "host",SID/SERVICE_NAME= "$NF}};if(val){print val;val=""}}'  Input_file
```

OR(non-one liner form of solution too as follows):

```
awk '{gsub(/\)|\(/,"");
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                                if($i=="HOST"){
                                                host=$(i+1)
                                              };
                                if($NF=="cd") {
                                                val="DB_NAME= "$1", HOST_NAME= "host",SID/SERVICE_NAME= "$NF
                                              }
                        };
      if(val)           {
                                print val;
                                val=""
                        }
     }
    '   Input_file
```

You could put "cd"''s place another service or ssid which you want to search too in above code.

Comment: it gives me a list of all hostnames, but i want to get a specific one (i know the sid/service_name)

Comment: it worked, thanks. Another question that is related to this question, it there a way to get the db_name value ?

Comment: please show the sample Input_file and expected output too

Comment: the input file is in the first comment, and the output should be db_name2 for example. i have the sid which in this example is blabla2 and i want to get the string db_name2

Comment: kindly refer my edit2 now and let me know if this helkps you.

Comment: it doesnt work, it prints the hostname and an error : awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=159) fatal: attempt to access field -1.  Mybe i wasnt so clear. the tnsnames has many records like the example above, the db_name may be also ravindersingn134(its an alias for the sid). i want to the find that alias(i dont need the hostname ). I have only the sid/service name.

Comment: So it means some of your lines are not having exact field names as per your shown sample Input_file, I am pretty sure on it

Comment: I put my real tnsnames.ora in the first command, it still doesnt work. Can you check it out ?

Comment: I dont know why but my first commot doesnt display it like it really is. In the first command it looks like every alias is taking 2 rows but in my real file it looks like that picture  : https://www.google.co.il/search?q=tnsnames.ora+get+host+for+service_name&rlz=1C1NHXL_iwIL730IL730&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUkayowMnSAhWFbxQKHaX5B3IQ_AUICCgD&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=sjImeu2Ig5b7VM:

Comment: It Indeed prints something but not the real hostname and alias(but the right sid). I think that it is because when your wrote the awk you thought that it is in the format of the format in my comment but it looks like the picture i sent.

Answer (score 1):

If perl is available try this command:

```
perl -nle 'BEGIN{$service = shift}
    $host = $1 if /HOST\s*=\s*([^\s\)]+)/i;
    print $host if /\((SID|SERVICE_NAME)\s*=\s*$service\)/;
' blabla tnsnames.ora
```

It stores the last host value found in `HOST = ...` and prints it when encounters `(**SID/SERVICE_NAME** = blabla)`